# Function pureness of void lambdas in Java

Tags: java, lambda

## Pure vs impure

By definition, a lambda expression/statement is a *pure function* if it doesn't mutate state and an *impure function* otherwise.  By state one means the arguments it receives or data in its context/enclosing environment.

### Producing a result

A lambda expression/statement may produce a result or not. That should not interfere with its function pureness aspect.

So one may reason about the following categories (impure ones mutate argument)

- pure function lambda producing a result (e.g. `x -> x + 1`)
- impure function lambda producing a results (e.g. `(StringBuilder sb) -> {sb.append("impure and proud of it"); return -3;}`)
- pure function void lambda (e.g. `x -> {}`)
- impure function void lambda (e.g. `(StringBuilder sb) -> sb.append("abc")`)

How do I determine the function pureness of the following lambdas:

- `x -> System.out.println(x)`
- `x -> Util.writeToDb(x)` 
  (Consider `writeToDb(int x)` a method that takes an `int` or a `String` as arguments, connects to a db using jdbc, inserts the argument in a ready table and closes the connection.)

Certainly in both cases the state of the universe changes with the invocation. However in formal terms, where does the state realm end?

Comment: the state of the universe does not affect level of pureness. only state of internal memory that is accessible to the running program (in other words, heap and static memories) so both functions are pure.

Comment: The term "pure" does not appear in the Java language specification. From a Haskell perspective, both of these functions have side effects, and neither are pure.

Comment: The examples of impurity in the first table will be deemed as "pure" by the JVM.
By this I mean that the lambdaMetafactory will reuse its instance whenever the same exact code appears in the program. `sb.append("impure and proud of it"); return -3;` inside a lambda.
A lambda is impure if it captures a non-final state coming from the outer scope of the lambda.
When a lambda "captures" a variable object, the JVM creates a new lambda instance with the reference of the captured object.
Because the JVM is unable to infer whether this object will remain equal, or change the next time this ...

Comment: lambda is re-created, it will be forced to create a new one with the likely new reference.
Also, I'm sure your answer is being displayed by Bing when discussing this subject, lmao.